# LWC set value in lightning-input and maxlength="99" does not work

Tags: javascript, salesforce, lwc

I would like set value of lightning-input after click to button quantity up, but it does not work.
And maxlength in input does not work too. It should be set to max 99, but it can be set also to 9999999999999999999.

html template:

```
<div>
  <lightning-button-group key={product.Id}>
    <lightning-button 
      name={product.Id}
      value={product.Id}  
      class="button" 
      label="-" 
      onclick={handleQuantityDown}>
    </lightning-button>
    <lightning-input 
      type="number" 
      name={product.Id} 
      value={textValue} 
      placeholder="1" 
      minlength="1" 
      maxlength="99" 
      onchange={handleChangeInput}>
    </lightning-input>
    <lightning-button 
      name={product.Id}
      value={product.Id}
      class="button" 
      label="+" 
      onclick={handleQuantityUp}>
    </lightning-button>
  </lightning-button-group>
</div>
<div>
  <lightning-button-group key={product.Id}>
    <lightning-button 
      name={product.Id}
      value={product.Id}  
      class="button" 
      label="-" 
      onclick={handleQuantityDown}>
    </lightning-button>
    <lightning-input 
      type="number" 
      name={product.Id} 
      value={textValue} 
      placeholder="1" 
      minlength="1" 
      maxlength="99" 
      onchange={handleChangeInput}>
    </lightning-input>
    <lightning-button 
      name={product.Id}
      value={product.Id}
      class="button" 
      label="+" 
      onclick={handleQuantityUp}>
    </lightning-button>
  </lightning-button-group>
</div>
```

js:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
  export default class Display extends LightningElement {
  clickedButtonQuantityPlus;

  handleQuantityUp(event) {
    this.clickedButtonQuantityPlus = event.target.name;  // get name/ProductID from the button
    let input = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input[name=' + this.clickedButtonQuantityPlus + ']');  // set input with ProductID from button
    input.value = input.value + 1;  // set input value
  }
}
```

How is it needed to edit?

Answer (score 2):

The maxlength determines the maximum number of characters allowed in the field and not the value.

To make the max value to be 99 you should use the following snippet.

```
<template>
    <lightning-input type="number" label="Input" maxlength="2">
    </lightning-input>
</template>
```

for more information you can refer to the below documentation link:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/specification

Comment: Yes, maxlength limits number of characters, not value. Yes, label is required. Thank you.

Comment: And how can I get or set value from input? When on page is more the same inputs. Only the names of inputs are different.
`this.template.querySelector('lightning-input[name=' + this.clickedButtonQuantityPlus + ']').value` 
where `this.clickedButtonQuantityPlus` is name of input does not work.

Comment: you can make use of onchange method in lightning-input to track the updates.
querying the template is not consider as the best practice.

Comment: It's possible get value from method handleChangeInput:
`import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
  export default class Display extends LightningElement {
  clickedButtonQuantityPlus;
  inputQuantity;

  handleChangeInput(event) {
    this.inputQuantity = event.detail.value;  // get value from input
  }
}`
But I would like to get value from input when somebody clicks to the buttonQuantityUp, or buttonQuantityDown or buttonAddToCart. And I don't know how can I do this by event onclick. Or should be used some other event? [Sample](https://pasteboard.co/JV1nHdc.png)

Comment: you should store the value in the component js var. if you are getting on clicks btn identify which btn was clicked on change the value accordingly. on change of value the component will rerender itself to show the latest value

Comment: Any code example? I don't know how to do this.